# plot predicted values from a moderated regression in R

Tags: r, regression, predict

The goal here is to plot the confidence intervals for a moderated and unmoderated regression. For an unmoderated regression, this is straightforward.

```
dependent <- c(0.0357264300, 0.0127688421, 0.0574075955, 0.0478508616, 0.8182810990, 0.2923778764, 0.0002984776, 0.0175975337, 0.1282831072, 0.1496447041, 0.0175852979)
independent <- c(13, 9, 54, 16, 1623, 120, 6, 30, 50, 117, 36)

model <- lm(dependent ~ independent)
newX <- seq(6, 1637, 1)
pred <- predict(model, newdata=data.frame(independent =newX), interval=c("confidence"), 
            level=0.95, type="response")

plot(independent, dependent)
abline(model)
lines(newX,pred[,2],col="red",lty=2)
lines(newX,pred[,3],col="red",lty=2)
```

[image]

However, when I try and repeat the procedure with a moderator, the output does not seem plausible. In this case, I expect that the moderator values decay with increasing values of the independent variable.

```
moderator <- c(0.03823529, 0.05325444, 0.14400000, 0.04289544, 0.25774178, 0.66298343, 1.00000000, 0.68181818, 0.70422535, 0.46987952, 0.55384615)
modelMod <- lm(dependent ~ moderator*independent)

# a decay function
func <- function(x, a, b){
res <- a*exp(-b*x)
return(res)
}

newModerator <- func(newX, a=1, b=0.001)

predMod <- predict(modelMod, newdata=data.frame(independent=newX, 
       moderator = newModerator), interval=c("confidence"), 
        level=0.95, type="response")

plot(independent, dependent)
lines(newX, predMod[,1])
lines(newX, predMod[,2], lty=2, col="red")
lines(newX, predMod[,3], lty=2, col="red")
```

[image]

Is this result correct? Is the result I am getting a result of an incorrect way to use the 'predict' function? I want the code to be homologous between the two regressions so that the visualization of the results is comparable.

Comment: I think that the approach is right, but perhaps the specified values aren't meaningful. I would nevertheless appreciate any comments on the approach